# VS 2015 CE WYSIWYG Editor not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

Since I reinstalled VS offline, today I started a new Xamarin.Forms Portable project and added a Forms Xaml Page (Select the portable project > Ctrl + Shift + A -> Select "Cross-Plattform"). When added, there was no wysiwyg editing possibility like before. Now I only get the ordinary X(A)ML with Syntax High-lighting.

Then I selected the Xaml file -> Context -> Open with... -> "Xaml-Designer with Coding" -> Ok but then I get a error that tells me, that VS is not able to open the file. I "should select a different Editor".

May someone help me?

Comment: Depends upon which Xamarin version your are running: i.e. for `ALPHA PREVIEW 3: CYCLE 8 : [Xamarin.VS] – 42397: The Xamarin.Forms Previewer is disabled on VS for this release.` So check your installed version against the release notes for that version: https://releases.xamarin.com

Comment: thanks for answer, but I use Xamarin.VS 4.1.1.3, the issue you mention is for Xamarin.VS 4.2.0.378 :(

Comment: I guess you did not read the release notes: `The Xamarin.Forms Previewer is currently only available in Xamarin Studio in the Alpha channel.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin.Forms previewer is not available on Visual Studio yet. You need to use the Xamarin Studio for now